# String containing exact value but can occur more than once

Tags: jquery

How can i check if a string contains the charachters of `"&nbsp;"` but there can be multiple of it like `"&nbsp;&nbsp;"` or `"&nbsp;&nbsp;"` etc?

The operation i do now (which only works for one instance of `"&nbsp;"`) is:

```
if($(this).html() == "&nbsp;")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

**[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kA1nP8)**

```
^(?:[ ]*&nbsp;[ ]*)+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/D1Wg7BQYZYjuhsCh)

---

**JavaScript**

```
if (/^(?:[ ]*&nbsp;[ ]*)+$/i.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

---

**Description**

```
/^(?:[ ]*&nbsp;[ ]*)+$/
    ^ Start of string
    (?:[ ]*&nbsp;[ ]*) Non-capturing Group 1 to infinite times [greedy]
        Char class [ ] 0 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
          The character  
            &nbsp; Literal &nbsp;
        Char class [ ] 0 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
          The character  
    $ End of string
```

Comment: It kinda works, but i need it to allow whitespaces through also.

Comment: @SamPettersson Updated to allow spaces

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
/^(\&nbsp;)+$/.test($(this).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple regex

```
if(/^(&nbsp;)+$/.test($.trim($(this).text())))
```

Comment: `$(this).text()` will not show `&nbsp;` but  `.html()` will. And `$.trim` will remove all extra spaces.

Comment: @techfoobar fixed... forgot the start ^ and $

Comment: @techfoobar Havent tested with the trim() but with out that it doesn't return true for "&nbsp;Hellooo"?

Comment: @SamPettersson - Thats because like @TusharGupta said, `.text()` won't return any `"&nbsp;"` - but will return `' '` instead. So when you trim the string the spaces are gone and the regex fails.